# How to calculate a measure with one hard-coded filter but still allow other slicers to apply?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have this calculation that computes an average using the past six months.

This works as expected, however when I use my slicers to filter on a specific branch the average remains the same, it does not filter based on the branch (slicer) selected on the visual.

How can I hard-code a date range as I am doing here, but allow any other slicers (other than date) to take effect in this DAX measure?

```
VAR result = CALCULATE(AVERAGE(FactLineItem[InvoiceAmount]), 
FILTER(ALLEXCEPT(FactLineItem, FactLineItem[BranchKey]) , FactLineItem[InvoiceDate] >= EDATE([MaxSaleDate],-6) && FactLineItem[InvoiceDate] <= [MaxSaleDate]))
```

The following approach seems to produce the same results as above.

```
VAR result = CALCULATE(AVERAGE(FactLineItem[InvoiceAmount]),
FILTER(ALL(FactLineItem) , FactLineItem[InvoiceDate] >= EDATE([MaxSaleDate],-6) && FactLineItem[InvoiceDate] <= [MaxSaleDate]))
```

Comment: Try to use [ALLSELECTED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/allselected-function-dax) instead of ALL in the second approach.

Comment: Hi, I tried this and it appears to work (had to use all but specify the invoicedate that i want to manually filter on:  VAR result = CALCULATE(AVERAGE(FactLineItem[InvoiceAmount]), ALL('Date'),
FILTER(ALL(FactLineItem[InvoiceDate]) , FactLineItem[InvoiceDate] >= EDATE([MaxSaleDate],-6) && FactLineItem[InvoiceDate] <= [MaxSaleDate])
)